# Vertical alignment multiple spans inside div with variable height (ui-select-multiple)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, ui-select

I use Multiselect from [AngularJS ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

My multiselect looks like this
http://plnkr.co/edit/zJRUW8STsGlrJ38iVwhI?p=preview

Spans can be arranged in multiple lines if there are many. I want to do nice vertical aligment for this.

I managed to do it for one line:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cs630525.vk.me](http://cs630525.vk.me/v630525759/14770/wc2J1ZbmX9E.jpg))</sub>

But it fails on multiple lines:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cs630525.vk.me](http://cs630525.vk.me/v630525759/14777/wUdetOjRVX0.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [cs630525.vk.me](http://cs630525.vk.me/v630525759/1477e/27QtEjdQlAM.jpg))</sub>

"nice vertical aligment" - paddings with same colors must be equal

[image]
<sub>(source: [cs630525.vk.me](http://cs630525.vk.me/v630525759/147d8/yzbFRSIGXl8.jpg))</sub>

**HTML**

```
  <ui-select multiple class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap form-control dropdown" 
             ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" ng-disabled="disabled">
      <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match" placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
        {{color}}
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap {
  padding: 0 3px;
  min-height: 34px;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.ui-select-match {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap input.ui-select-search {
  min-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap > div {
  min-height: 32px;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: .ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-match-item { display:block; }   add this to your csss

Comment: So what is this supposed to look like? *"nice vertical aligment"*...is vague.

Comment: @Paulie_D , i updated my post with the answer to your question)

Comment: You're demo doesn't show the issue...can update it to show the actual problem?

Answer (score 3):

Add below code to your css

```
.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-match-item { 
   display:block; 
}
```

Comment: thanks but your solution works bad for me -
[screen](http://cs630525.vk.me/v630525759/147c8/doXyqeY_6-o.jpg)